# Spring batch Job Failing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

All the steps being passed still the job is completed with failed status.

```
 @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("person-job")
                 .start(initializeBatch())
                 .next(readBodystep())
                 .on("STOPPED")
                 .stopAndRestart(initializeBatch())
                 .end()
                .validator(batchJobParamValidator)
                .incrementer(jobParametersIncrementer)
                .listener(jobListener)
                .build();
    }

@Bean
public Flow preProcessingFlow() {
    return new FlowBuilder<Flow>("preProcessingFlow")
            .start(extractFooterAndBodyStep())
            .next(readFooterStep())
            .build();
}
@Bean
public Step initializeBatch() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("initializeBatch")
            .flow(preProcessingFlow())
            .build();

public Step readBodystep() {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("readChunkStep")
                .<PersonDTO, PersonBO>chunk(10)
                .reader(personFileBodyReader)
                .processor(itemProcessor())
                .writer(dummyWriter)
                .listener(new ReadFileStepListener())
                .listener(personFileBodyReader)
                .build();
    }
```

is anything wrong with the above configuration?
When I am removing the stopAndRestart configuration, it is getting passed.

Comment: `initializeBatch` is the first step of your job. Adding `stopAndRestart(initializeBatch())` on the first step of a job does not make sense to me. Why do you need that?

Comment: First step is to downlaod the file from server. So I thought to start from that step if number of record in the footer not same as no. of record read. That means file is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, it is not `stopAndRestart` that you need, it is rather setting `allowStartIfComplete` on the step. With that, if the job fails, the step will be re-executed even if it was successfully completed in the previous run.